# In an UpdateView with the form_valid over-written, how does django know where to redirect to?

Tags: django, django-views

In a generic FormView, the docs say that upon success, it will redirect to the `success_url` attribute.
If I happen to have an `UpdateView`, and rewrite the `form_valid` like so:

```
class PreferenceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(PreferenceUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

returning simply `super(PreferenceUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)` instead of something like `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`
, how does the view know where to redirect to?
When should I and when do I not have to specify the redirect?

Comment: You haven't really overwritten the form_valid, because you're recruit calling the original version which specifies where to redirect to.

Comment: In that case, since I never specified a success_url the `super` class, where does it get the redirect?  Also, then what does it mean to overwrite the form_valid? Does re-defining the form_valid simply mean I am adding my own code *on top of* the original form_valid?

Comment: Firstly, in the example you given there is absolutely no point in overriding that method. You would only do so if you actually wanted to do something as well as or instead of the redirect, eg adding a message or saving a related object. The default success_url is to found by calling the model's `get_absolute_url` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do plan on instantiating another object within the form_valid. So if the `success_url` is found by calling the model's `get_absolute_url`, then I assume if I have a specific endpoint I want to redirect to, I can always `return redirect()`, but if I specify a `model = __` on the view, I can simply `return super().form_valid()`. Is that the right way of viewing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the extend link is:

```
FormMixin->ModelFormMixin->BaseUpdateView->UpdateView
```

then `super(PreferenceUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)` will call `form_valid` in `FormMixin`,which source code is:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    """
    Returns the supplied success URL.
    """
    if self.success_url:
        # Forcing possible reverse_lazy evaluation
        url = force_text(self.success_url)
    else:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")
    return url

def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL.
    """
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

If you want to specify the redirect,override `success_url` in your `PreferenceUpdateView` class like:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
class PreferenceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('preference_list')
```

or override `get_success_url` method:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    """
    Returns the supplied success URL.
    """
    return reverse_lazy('preference_list')
```

if you want your success_url change according to instance :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
    self.success_url = reverse('preference_detail', kwargs={'pk': instance.id})
    return super(PreferenceUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```